# Gradient of a Frobenium norm cost Function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, frobenius-groups

Folks - Please help. What's the gradient for the cost function below?

$ D(Y||AX)=\frac{1}{2} ||Y-AX||^2_F $

Additional info -

-need to get the derivative of that with respect to A.
-Multiplicative NMF Algorithms Based on the Squared Euclidean Distance

Comment: You should add some context to the question in order to avoid downvotes and the question being closed. Some common way is to show your work on the problem, add what you know about the problem and closely related info. Maybe also add definitions.

Comment: @PaulPlummer That's the point man. I haven't had any matrix calculus in my undergrad and I've exhausted all the solutions I am aware of - vectorization, chain rule) yet I can't get it. I tried googling but couldn't find any.

Comment: I am just saying that problem statement questions are normally closed, even just adding a sentence or two about the problem, and/or where it comes from can improve its reception.

Comment: Done putting some info.

Comment: You are differentiating the quantity, $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} (Y_{ij} - (AX)_{ij})^2$. Have you tried filling in $(AX)_{ij}$, and differentiating with respect to a component of $A$?

Comment: I upvoted your question now. Can you please accept an answer if you are satisfied by the answer? I also would advice you to not use 'please help' in your question. People will definetly help you, if they know the answer and there is no need to say 'please help', although probably intended to be friendly. It is just how math.stackexchange works. ;)

Comment: Sure @Pedro. Am still new so I'm still adjusting. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
J = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} \left(\sum_k a_{ik}x_{kj} - y_{ij}\right)^2.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial A} =
\frac{\partial J}{\partial a_{lm}} = \sum_{ij} \left(\sum_k a_{ik}x_{kj} - y_{ij}\right) \frac{\partial \left(\sum_k a_{ik}x_{kj} - y_{ij}\right)}{\partial a_{lm}} =\\
= \sum_{ij} \left(\sum_k a_{ik}x_{kj} - y_{ij}\right) \frac{\partial \left(\sum_k a_{ik}x_{kj}\right)}{\partial a_{lm}} =\\
= \sum_{ij} \left(\sum_k a_{ik}x_{kj} - y_{ij}\right) \delta_{il}x_{mj} =\\
= \sum_{j} \left(\sum_k a_{lk}x_{kj} - y_{lj}\right) x_{mj} =\\
= (AX-Y)X^\top.
$$

The following [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) properties were used
$$
\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, & i = j\\
0, & i \neq j
\end{cases}.
$$
Similary
$$
\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial a_{kl}} = \begin{cases}
1, & i = k \text{ and } j = l\\
0, & i \neq k \text { or } j \neq l
\end{cases} = \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl}.
$$
Eliminating $\delta_{ij}$ is done via summation
$$
\sum_j \delta_{ij} x_j = \sum_{j \neq i} \delta_{ij} x_j + x_i = x_i.
$$
In other words
$$
\sum_i \delta_{ij} \bullet \to \bullet \text{ with } i \text{ replaced by }j.
$$

Let's consider the tricky part
$$
\frac{\partial \left(\sum_k a_{ik}x_{kj}\right)}{\partial a_{lm}} = 
\sum_k \frac{\partial a_{ik}}{\partial a_{lm}} x_{kj} + \sum_k a_{ik}
\frac{\partial x_{kj}}{\partial a_{lm}} = \sum_{k} \delta_{il}\delta_{km} x_{kj} = \delta_{il} x_{mj}
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27013/discussion-on-answer-by-uranix-gradient-of-a-frobenium-norm-cost-function).

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=(AX-Y)$, then the function and its differential can be expressed in terms of the Frobenius (:) product as 
$$\eqalign{
  f &= \frac{1}{2}\,M:M \cr\cr
  df &= M:dM \cr
     &= (AX-Y):dA\,X \cr
     &= (AX-Y)X^T:dA \cr
}$$
Since $df=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}):dA\,\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} &= (AX-Y)X^T \cr
}$$
If you dislike Frobenius products, you can replace them with traces, e.g. $\,{\rm tr}(A^TB)=A:B$

Comment: Why do we solve using AX-Y not Y-AX- original notation?

Comment: It doesn't affect the value of $f$, or the solution.  And avoiding a bunch of  unnecessary sign-flipping makes the logic easier to follow. You'll notice that uranix did the same thing, it just makes more sense.

Comment: Actually, it does. The sign gets switched. So any more Mathematical explanation on this such as a certain property?

Comment: @GJM Here's the Mathematical property that john316 and uranix are invoking, $(-M):(-M)=(M):(M)$